# Object displacement after browser resize (CSS media queries)

Tags: css, media-queries

I've got a really weird problem with the placement of my navigation after resizing the browser window. The best way to explain it is to show it I think.

After resizing to width < 600px and back to width > 600px:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/kjwbx85atcgcedu/Screen%20Shot%202014-02-16%20at%2018.57.50.png

Live version (404 page since about page has not been made yet):
http://lakitna.nl/responsive/?p=About

This issue is in Chrome. In safari the displacement is different, but also there. Other browsers have not been tested yet.

I am using media queries in my HTML header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/global.css"    type="text/css" media="only screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style600.css"  type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-width: 600px)" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style1024.css" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 1024px)" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylefull.css" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: 1025px)" />
```

Do you have any idea what the problem is and/or were it comes from? I simply do not know where to look.

Comment: If I have it open in devtools in Chrome its 120px in height for a moment when I resize up the window again and it stays in the wrong place. Havent found the culprit why though.

Comment: Thank you Henrik. 120px is the height of the width < 600px.. So perhaps it somehow can not shake the height.
Further research on my part showed me that the issue only exists in Chrome, the previously mentioned issue on Safari was a transition-issue. Firefox renders it correctly and even IE9 renders it correctly. I will contact Google about this issue.

Comment: Then maybe it has to do with presidency of the CSS rules? Also, its 67px off (setting `top: -67px` aligns it). Might mean something?